# Part of layout scrollable android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying a linearlayout scrollable in android app. I need it this way.

when user swipes up, Box 1 can move out of screen and box 2 should be fixed at top of the screen and box 3 is a scrollable box. How to implement this? I think image helps you to understand.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Row1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Row2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Row3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Row4" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Row5" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Row6" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Row7" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Row8" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Row9" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I actually tried with a scroll view, as a result everything is getting scrolled. So, my code will not help.

Comment: just paste your code here i will explain u

Comment: first change height and width from fill_parent to match_parent. fill_parent is deprecated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually need Pinned header and found this more useful.

This github project is actually working(Only few tweaks in code). @rahulritesh link also helped me. But this is more understandable for me.

https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using ListView where the section header remains at the top. See this for an example: https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView